# How to predict the delay of a higher order digital filter

Tags: signal-processing

My last question on this was a minimal example. I start with the following:

```
freq=0.1;
input=Table[Sin[freq t],{t,1,250}];
```

I use results above in two digital filters below.

```
transferFunction1=TransferFunctionModel[{{{0.13793103448275862*z}},{{-0.9+z}}},z,SamplingPeriod->1];
filtered1=RecurrenceFilter[transferFunction1,input];
output1=Transpose[{Range[1,Length@filtered1],filtered1}];
Clear[mag,timeShift];
NonlinearModelFit[Part[output1,130;;250],mag*Sin[freq(timeShift+t)],{mag,timeShift},t]["BestFit"]
```

[image: first fit]

Next I use the transferFunction1 to compute the delay due to the filter above and I get the same amount of delay.

```
transFunctAtFreq1=Part[transferFunction1@Exp[freq*I],1,1];
timeShift1=ArcTan[Re@transFunctAtFreq1,Im@transFunctAtFreq1]/freq
```

[image: timeShift1]
The above is a summary what is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264227/how-to-predict-the-delay-of-a-digital-filter/264262#264262). However, the same approach doesn't work with the  higher order filter below.

```
transferFunction2=TransferFunctionModel[{{{0.06698729810778067`+0.1830127018922193` z+0.1830127018922193` z^2+0.06698729810778067` z^3}},{{z-0.5}}},z,SamplingPeriod->1];
filtered2=RecurrenceFilter[transferFunction2,input];
output2=Transpose[{Range[1,Length@filtered2],filtered2}];
Clear[mag,timeShift];
NonlinearModelFit[Part[output2,130;;250],mag*Sin[freq(timeShift+t)],{mag,timeShift},t]["BestFit"]
```

[image: second fit]
Next I try to use transferFunction2 to compute the delay of 2.49 that was found above using NonLinearModelFit, but I get the wrong value.

```
transFunctAtFreq2=Part[transferFunction2@Exp[freq I],1,1];
timeShift2=ArcTan[Re@transFunctAtFreq2,Im@transFunctAtFreq2]/freq
```

[image: second delay]
How can I use transferFunction2 to find the delay due to the filter?

Comment: The delay in transferFunction2 excludes the transport delay in the pipeline.  For your third-order filter, there are two more samples of delay than for the first-order filter in your earlier example.  This is the 'missing' two samples (2.49012-0.490123).

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to solve it.

```
transferFunction2=TransferFunctionModel[{{{0.06698729810778067`+0.1830127018922193` z+0.1830127018922193` z^2+0.06698729810778067` z^3}},{{z-0.5}}},z,SamplingPeriod->1];
filtered2=RecurrenceFilter[transferFunction2,input];
output2=Transpose[{Range[1,Length@filtered2],filtered2}];
Clear[mag,timeShift];
NonlinearModelFit[Part[output2,130;;250],mag*Sin[freq(timeShift+t)],{mag,timeShift},t]["BestFit"]
```

[image]
Above I get the delay using NonLinearModelFit. Below I get the delay using transferFunction2

```
Exponent[Part[transferFunction2,1,1,1,1],z]-
Exponent[Part[transferFunction2,1,2,1,1],z]- 
ArcTan[Re@transFunctAtFreq2,Im@transFunctAtFreq2]/freq
```

[image]